# sqlite select statement with order by

Tags: sql, sqlite

i have a database for number of bills and i want to select the last number 
i used

```
select billnum from bills  order by billnum desc limit 1
```

but it works only with numbers < 10
[samples of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrM8O.png)

Comment: share your table structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you are storing the value as text rather than an integer.

Try casting:

```
order by cast(billnum as integer) desc
```

If `billnum` includes decimal points, you can use `decimal` instead of `integer`.

If `billnum` has no leading zeros, then an alternative is:

```
order by length(billnum) desc, billnum desc
```

Comment: I would suggest to use the MAX function instead of an order by and limit 1: select max(cast(billnum as integer) from bills

Answer (score 0):

you could use `max()` if you want all ties rows

```
select t.* from bills t where t.billnum= (select max(billnum) from bills)
```